# Making sidebar-nav tabs active?

Tags: html, css, tabs, sidebar

I have a sidebar-nav that has several tabs. How can I make the current tab viewed by users active/highlighted ??
I tried the active class but it seemed to make one tab active constantly!
any help would be greatly appreciated

Here is my view:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <li class="sidebar-brand">
                <a href="/ci/index.php/adel_ctl/member"> KU Faculty</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <hr style='margin-top:2px; color:#000;margin-right:30px;'>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/ci/index.php/adel_ctl/profile/<?=$id?>">My Profile</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/ci/index.php/adel_ctl/research/<?=$id?>">Reseasrch</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/ci/index.php/adel_ctl/teaching/<?=$id?>">Teaching</a></li>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/ci/index.php/adel_ctl/experience/<?=$id?>">Experience</a></li>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/ci/index.php/adel_ctl/publications/<?=$id?>">Publications</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/ci/index.php/adel_ctl/resume/<?=$id?>">Resume</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/ci/index.php/adel_ctl/about/<?=$id?>">About us</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to match url path with jQuery and add "active" class to it with:

```
$(function(){
    var this_url = window.location.pathname;
    var list_sidebar_link = $(".sidebar-nav li a");
    $(list_sidebar_link).each(function (i, item) {
        var the_a = list_sidebar_link[i];
        if (this_url == $(the_a).attr('href')) {
            $(the_a).addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but could you please explain a little bit more as I have never used jQuery/js. The code you provided, where should I add it??

Comment: JQuery is a JavaScript library that helps write less code by using HTML selectors. There is much more to it, but in this situation it muches the explanation. http://jquery.com you can add it to your page by adding `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` into <head> section or just above the closing body tag. After that place the code snippet bellow it inside <script> tags.

Comment: OK, I did this :`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>‌
    <script $(function(){
    var path = $('.sidebar-nav li').find('a').attr('href');
    if (path === window.location.pathname) {
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});>

    </script>` but still current tab is not active

Comment: Do you have CSS for .active class?

Comment: Yes I do,  .active { color: #000;}

Comment: I just did, still does not work. when replaced the code, the "_sidebar_link" is white, maybe the code is not correct.

Comment: See this: http://jsfiddle.net/g74utzf4/5/ When you click the "run" you'll se the Reseasrch link getting border. That is because it's href is set to "/_display/" (which is the location path of run of jsfiddle). Look at it and see what is different from your setup.

Comment: The only difference I have is that the code is in my html view whereas in your case it is placed in the javascript. can I put it in bootstrap.min.js?? I did but it didn't work as well. It is really strange. Thank you so much for trying, if you have any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Maybe you can post a view source of the whole page if it not privacy compromising. As a gist or pastebin.

Comment: you said href"/_display/" is the location of path of run of jsfiddle!? so what is mine?? this could be the error I have. in my routes.php config I have this: $route['default_controller'] = "index";
$route['404_override'] = ''; do I need to change it?? Thanks a lot

Comment: It suppose to take whatever is in your `href=""`. The "/_display/" is only used to show that it works.